# UIScrollView content inset defined by a height of a view outside of the subtree

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

Given a view hierarchy:

```
- View `container`
    - UIScrollView `scrollView`
        - UIView `content`
    - UIView `footer`
```

**I would like the `UIScrollView.contentInset.bottom` to be equal to `footer.bounds.height`.**

**Question: Can this be expressed using Auto Layout?**

Now, there is a very evident brute-force approach that I am aware of and that works:

1. Observe changes to the `bounds` property of the `footer`
2. `scrollView.contentInset.bottom = -footer.bounds.height` once `footer`'s parent has finished `layoutSubviews()`.

Or alternatively I could have a constraint between `content.bottom` and `scrollView.bottom` (which, as, I'm sure, you are aware, indicates the bottom content inset for non-ambiguously size content) and have its constant altered each time the `footer` bounds change.

But the point is that all of those approaches are very on-the-nose, really makes me uncomfortable for the terrible code they produce so I am wondering:

**Can this be expressed using Auto Layout?**

I have attempted to do the following:

```
content.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footer.topAnchor)
```

Hoping that `content.bottomAnchor` would be treated as the bottom inset of the scroll view content, but nope - Auto Layout literally treats it as me constraining content's bottom to the footer's top.

Comment: Your approach seems confusing without more context. My initial thought is: why not constrain the bottom of the scroll view to the top of the footer view?

Comment: @DonMag oh no, this is out of option, it would be too easy then. The thing is that the footer is transparent and I need the scroll view to be under it so that the content of the scroll view is under it so that it's visible there because it's the design requirement. It's in a fashion similar to UITabBar with automatic content insets - you can see the underlying content through the blur.

Comment: OK - I have an auto-layout solution for you. Are you laying this out in Storyboard / IB? Or doing it all via code?

Comment: @DonMag we are doing it via code. NSLayoutConstraint, NSLayoutAnchor, SnapKit - we do it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - one approach...

As of iOS 11 (I'm assuming you don't need to target earlier than that), a subview of a `UIScrollView` can be constrained to the scroll view's `Frame Layout Guide`. This made it easy to add non-scrolling UI elements to the scroll view hierarchy.

Based on this hierarchy:

```
- view
    - scrollView
        - contentView
            - element1
            - element2
            - element3
            - UILayoutGuide
        - footerView
```

What we'll do is:

- add all the "scrollable" elements to the contentView
- **plus** add a `UILayoutGuide` to the contentView which will serve as or "bottom" scrollable element
- add the footerView to the scrollView ***last*** so it is at the top of the z-order
- constrain the footerView to the scrollView's `Frame Layout Guide` so it stays put
- constrain the heightAnchor of our `UILayoutGuide` equal to the heightAnchor of the footerView

Because a `UILayoutGuide` is a non-rendering view, it will not be visible but it will create the space from the bottom of our last *viewable* element to the bottom of the contentView -- and it will automatically change height if/when the footerView changes height.

Here's a complete example - scrollView / contentView / 3 imageViews / layout guide / translucent footerView:

```
class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        return v
    }()

    let contentView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return v
    }()

    let footerView: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.textColor = .white
        v.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24.0, weight: .bold)
        v.text = "Footer View"
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.65)
        return v
    }()

    var imgView1: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        v.image = UIImage(systemName: "1.circle")
        v.tintColor = .white
        return v
    }()

    var imgView2: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        v.image = UIImage(systemName: "2.circle")
        v.tintColor = .white
        return v
    }()

    var imgView3: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        v.image = UIImage(systemName: "3.circle")
        v.tintColor = .white
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add 3 image views as the content we want to see
        contentView.addSubview(imgView1)
        contentView.addSubview(imgView2)
        contentView.addSubview(imgView3)

        // add contentView to srollView
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

        // add footer view to scrollView last so it's at the top of the z-order
        scrollView.addSubview(footerView)

        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        [scrollView, contentView, footerView, imgView1, imgView2, imgView3].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        // "spacer" for bottom of scroll content
        //  we'll constrain it to the height of the footer view
        let spacerGuide = UILayoutGuide()
        contentView.addLayoutGuide(spacerGuide)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let svCLG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let scFLG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain scrollView view 40-pts on all 4 sides to view (safe-area)
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -40.0),

            // contentView view 0-pts top / leading / trailing / bottom to scrollView contentLayoutGuide
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // contentView width == scrollView frameLayoutGuide width
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scFLG.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),


            // imgView1 to top of contentView
            imgView1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // imgView1 width / height
            imgView1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
            imgView1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),

            // imgView1 centerX to contentView centerX
            imgView1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),


            // imgView2 top to bottom of imgView1 + 20-pt spacing
            imgView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView1.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),

            // imgView2 width / height
            imgView2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            imgView2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 280.0),

            // imgView2 centerX to contentView centerX
            imgView2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),


            // imgView3 top to bottom of imgView2 + 20-pt spacing
            imgView3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView2.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),

            // imgView3 width / height
            imgView3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 280.0),
            imgView3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320.0),

            // imgView3 centerX to contentView centerX
            imgView3.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),


            // spacerGuide top to bottom of actual content
            // spacerGuide top to imgView3 bottom
            spacerGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView3.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // spacerGuide to leading / trailing / bottom of contentView
            spacerGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            spacerGuide.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            spacerGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // footerView to leading / trailing / bottom of scrollView frameLayoutGuide
            //  (constrained to frameLayoutGuide so it won't scroll)
            footerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scFLG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            footerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scFLG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            footerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scFLG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // footerView height == scrollView height with 0.25 multiplier
            //  (so it will change height when scrollView changes height, such as device rotation)
            footerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scFLG.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.25),

            // finally, spacerGuide height equal to footerView height
            spacerGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.heightAnchor),

        ])

    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Scrolled to the bottom:

[image]

and rotated (so we see the footerView height change) scrolled all the way to the bottom:

[image]

---

**Edit**

The answer to the *specific* question is: you can't.

A scroll view's `contentInset` is not an object to which you can add constraints... it's a Property of the scroll view. Much like you could not constrain a scroll view's `.backgroundColor` to an auto-layout constraint.

Comment: Great workaround! Amazing idea - to have a dummy view or a layout guide embedded to the place where the contentInset is supposed to be and have it's height synchronized with the `footer`. Nice job, I really hope they pay you well wherever you work! @DonMag sadly, I will not mark this answer as right just yet because it doesn't answer my question. It works around the usage of contentInset, but the question is how to work exactly WITH the contentInset and manage it via Auto Layout.

Comment: @IsaacCarolWeisberg - I added an **Edit** to answer the *specific* question. I probably should have clarified that to begin with.

Comment: yeah, I got you. After doing very little of my own research I will just mark your answer as correct because it is highly probably so.

Comment: Anything you can do about verticalScrollIndicatorInsets so that they dont end up under that footer view?

Comment: @CalebK - we cannot add *constraints* to the `verticalScrollIndicator` ... we would need to set `scrollView.verticalScrollIndicatorInsets.bottom` when the height of the "footer" view changes. In that case, it would make sense to set the `scrollView.contentInset.bottom` at the same time (instead of using the constrained guide).

Answer (score 0):

Landed here after looking for a solution, in my case the scroll view is actually a `UICollectionView`, so adding "helper" elements to the layout (as suggested by another answer) would have been more challenging (changing `dataSource` logic etc)

I ended up doing the following:

(This example assumes you have a `bottomView` attached to the bottom of the screen and you want your scrollView / collectionView to be inset based on it)

Set `scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`

Then in your View Controller, do this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.scrollView.contentInset = .init(top: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.minY,
                                         left: 0,
                                         bottom: bottomView.frame.height,
                                         right: 0)
}
```

Note that if you also want to account for left and right safe area (e.g. landscape avoiding iPhone notch), you can do:

```
[...]
left: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.minX
[...]
right: self.view.frame.width - self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.maxX
```